# Access method in another interface of same class

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I'm stuck on this problem, please help me.
I have a ViewController with class name: FLViewController. In the .m file, I declare some other interfaces:

```
@interface FLViewController (InternalMethods)
- (void)updateButtonStates;
@end

@interface FLViewController (AVCaptureManagerDelegate) <AVCaptureManagerDelegate>
-(void)adMobProcess
@end
```

In the implementation of FLViewController, I call method `adMobProcess` of Interface `FLViewController (AVCaptureManagerDelegate)` but the compiler said that "No visible @interface for `FLViewController` declares selector `adMobProcess`"

I can move the method above into the implementation of FLViewCOntroller (currently it is placed in the category AVCaptureManagerDelegate) however, I want to know how to call the method in another category.

Comment: Simplest is to just declare all the methods in the main interface.  They can also be declared in protocols adopted by the interface -- there will be no conflict.  If you need to call a method in another protocol, first cast to it.  Eg, `[(id <AvCaptureManagerDelegate) somePtr adMobProcess]`.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring your categories inside the .m file (which limits their scope to that one file), you've effectively declared some private methods for `FLViewController`. If this is what you want, you don't need categories.

Categories in Objective-C are meant to be reused. So you want to declare your categories in a header file (or files), and include those headers in any .m file where you use them.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I call the methods placed inside categories from the implementation of same Class. Here I'm declaring some categories in same .m file.

Comment: If your category is declared in an .h file, you just include that file and you can call the methods from the category. I'm not sure how to use categories declared in an .m file (mainly because doing so seems pointless to begin with.) Why do you want to have private categories?

Comment: Oh, normally I don't do that, but I'm fixing bugs from other developers :)

Comment: @lenhhoxung: just remove the category declarations from the .m file, and voilà, problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause. I didn't declare method signature in the Category, just only the method implementation in the Category implementation block.I declared the method and it works.

Comment: I've noticed too, don't forget in your Prefix.pch file to have them in the import statements in the "correct order"